# Como adicionar um iframe por meio do JS?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Estou tentando adicionar um iframe simples em uma página html, mas não está funcionando:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.google.com.br/");
document.getElementsByClassName('col-12 col-md-4').appendChild(ifrm);
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O trecho de código `document.getElementsByClassName` traz um `array` de informação para funcionar com o seu código precisa indicar a posição, nesse exemplo eu sei que tem uma posição por isso `[0]` e após `appendChild`:

```js
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.google.com.br/");
document.getElementsByClassName('col-12')[0]
     .appendChild(ifrm);
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
```

Observe no `console.log`

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('col-12'));
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
```

que demonstra a quantidade de elementos que são selecionados.

Comment: Excelente. E como eu faria para estilizar esse iframe direto do js?

Comment: @DiegoCândido https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927012/javascript-createelement-style-problem dá uma olhada!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("conteudo").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://assets.b9.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/https___hypebest.com_image_2019_12_coca-cola-insiders-club-subscription-service-info-1-1170x720.jpg"></iframe>';
</script>
```

Olá! Essa seria uma forma de fazer também.